# Finding results from primary and associated tables

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm just starting to work with CakePHP v3 after some years of v1.3, so there's a few things to I'm at a loss for, or rather at a loss as to how to do it 'properly'

I have 2 tables (products and data) that I want to search. However, the keywords provided by the end user may match the products.title or one of the data.value fields.  I want a single query to return all of the results for pagination, but can't seem to get the OR component to cross the products and data tables.

The following code (in pieces as I've been trying all sorts of things)

```
$query = $this->Products->find("all");
$query->select($this->Products);
$query->contain(['Data']);
$query->where("MATCH(Products.code, Products.title) AGAINST(:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$query->orWhere("MATCH(Data.value) AGAINST(:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$query->bind(":search", $terms);
$query->select(["relevance" => "MATCH(Products.code, Products.title) AGAINST(:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)"]);
$this->paginate['sortWhitelist'] = ['code', 'title', 'uom', 'relevance'];
$products = $this->paginate($query);
$this->set(compact('products'));
```

returns the following error

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Data.value' in 'where clause'

and when checking the query I can see because it has not joined the data table to the Products, and the where clause therefore fails. Using the matching() method doesn't seem to allow the returning of results where it's in the products but not the data, or vise versa.

How do I construct my query statement so as to achieve something like the following query (specifically the 'where' conditions, I've got the fields themselves sorted)

```
SELECT 
  Products.id, Products.title, [etc.],
  MATCH(Products.code, Products.title) AGAINST('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  + MATCH(Data.value) AGAINST('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  AS `relevance` 
FROM 
  products Products 
LEFT JOIN
  data Data
  on Data.product_id = Products.id
WHERE 
  MATCH(Products.code, Products.title) AGAINST('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  or
  MATCH(Data.value) AGAINST('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I of course want to use prepared statements and bind() to assist with the sanitization and reuse of the user data.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, moments later I solved it.

In the end, rather than using `$query->contain(['Data']);`

I had to use `$query->leftJoinWith('Data')`

Once that was swapped out, it worked!